# Windows Scheduled Task passwords

Tags: passwords, windows

When you create a Scheduled Task in Windows, it gives you the option of running the task as a different user, including saving the password.

How secure is the password that is stored?

Comment: To my reckoning, it must either store the password as plain text (probably not that likely), or reversibly-encrypted (which really reduces to security-by-obfuscation), but perhaps I have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified that, but the obvious way on windows would be to use [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261) with `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

At least that is the way passwords are stored in SQL Server Management Studio... reversable... ;-)